# Misconception in partial derivatives of Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, linear-algebra, calculus

Let us consider a Lorentz transformation of four vectors from frame S to S' where S' is moving with relative velocity $\textbf{v}$ with respect to S. The boost is given by
$$t'=\gamma(t-vx), \quad x'=\gamma(x-vt), \quad y'=y, \quad z'=z.$$
The inverse transformation is given by
$$t=\gamma(t'+vx'), \quad x=\gamma(x'+vt'), \quad y=y', \quad z=z'.$$
Now here comes the crucial part. Notice that
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} = \gamma, \quad \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} = \gamma. \tag{1}$$
I have thought about this for a while, but more thoughts always lead me to the same conclusion that this is true.

However, then we have a problem:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \gamma \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \tag{2}.$$
This seems fine. Continue:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} = \gamma \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} \tag{3}.$$
This also seems fine. Continue:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}=\gamma \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \gamma \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} = \gamma^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}$$

where we have reached a contradiction since $\gamma^2 \neq 1$.

Where's have I messed up in (1), (2), (3)?

Comment: how did you get (1)?

Comment: You neglected the time derivatives.

Comment: Can you explain how you got (2)?

Comment: @WillO, no, I mean you obtain (2) from (1)

Comment: @WillO You can’t.

Comment: (1) is correct. (2) and (3) are incorrect.

Comment: @G.Smith:  well, I knew that of course.  But I thought it might help the OP to give a little thought to the matter.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny:  How do you obtain (2) from (1)?

Comment: The only way to obtain an incorrect equation from a correct equation is by making a mistake.

Comment: @WillO by forgetting the time partial derivative and replacing (1) in (2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot that $x'$ is not only function of $x$, but also of $t$: $x' = x'(x, t)$. Similarly, $x=x(x', t')$. Hence:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial t'}$$